# how to limit Number of (dots) indicators count as 3 of Carousel?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, carousel

```
 this.state ={
  elements: [{title: 'title1'}, {title: 'title2'}, {title: 'title3'},
   {title: 'title4'}, {title: 'title5'}, {title: 'title6'}, {title: 
   'title7'}, {title: 'title8'}, {title: 'title9'}]
 }

 <Carousel
  ref='carousel'
  hideIndicators={false}
 >
  { this.props.elements.map((element, index) =>
     <View> <Text> {element.title}</Text> </View>
   )}
 </Carousel>
```

There are 12 indicators in the image but I want to limit the count of indicators of carousel.
I want to display only 3 indicators (dots) on the screen.

Please suggest if anyone know the solution.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do it, so your elements array would always keep 2 elements no matter what and you can have another array that stores other values of the indicators.

```
this.state ={
  allElements: [{title: 'title1'}, {title: 'title2'}, {title: 'title3'},
            {title: 'title4'}, {title: 'title5'}, {title: 'title6'},{title: 
'title7'}, {title: 'title8'}, {title: 'title9'}]
 },
start: 0,
end: 2,
elements: [{title: 'title]}, {title: 'title2}, {title: 'title3'}]

// Here is your update method that increases you start and end value by three and based on that value updates your elements array

update() => {
  start += 3;
  end += 3;
  this.state.elements = null;
  this.state.allElements.map((element, index) => 
     if(index >= start && index <= end) {
      elements.push(allElements[index]);
     }
  )
}

<Carousel
 ref='carousel'
 hideIndicators={false}
>
{ this.props.elements.map((element, index) =>
 <View> <Text> {element.title}</Text> </View>
 )}
</Carousel>
```

I might not be exactly correct on the syntax but you get the understanding, like if the person click on the next arrow then you `increment` start and end by `3` and if the person clicks on the prev arrow,then you `decrement` the start and end value by `3`.

Now to update your state, read here how you can update your state - https://learn.co/lessons/react-updating-state

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the use of this 'update()' method as you have not called it anywhere?

Comment: @kalyani_jamunkar I have updated my answer, please have a look now